# Add mutiple values to one column

Tags: php, silverstripe, sugarcrm

We are working on a website based on SilverStripe and this site is connected with a SugarCRM database.

We have created a Form with a `CheckboxSet` with multiple values and store it a variable called `$data['Interessen']`

```
$set_entry_parameters = array(
    "session" => $session_id,
    "module_name" => "Contacts",
    "name_value_list" => array(
        array(
            "name" => "interessen_c", 
            "value" => $data['Interessen']['fotografie']
        ),
        array(
            "name" => "interessen_c", 
            "value" => $data['Interessen']['dance']
        )
    )
);
```

Now the last array with `"interessen_c"` overwrites the previous values. We want to add more than one value at one time.

How is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? It's hard to know how to reproduce your problem at the moment

Comment: U can directly use like "name_value_list"=>json_encode(array($data['Interessen']['fotografie'], $data['Interessen']['dance'], $data['Interessen']['etc']));

While retrieving u can decode it so that you will get the plain array as before like: json_decode(set_entry_parameters["name_value_list"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents of *$data['Interessen']* can only have values from a fixed list of possibilities, I'd recommend making the field *interessen_c* into type `multienum` ("Multi-Selection Dropdown" field).

For that field create a list of all available items in Sugar (e.g. in Studio or creating the app_list_strings entry manually via code).

Sugar will then support multiple values in this field and display them nicely.

If your program writes the data by communicating with the Sugar REST API you can then just pass the `$data['Interessen']` array as the value for `interessen_c` and Sugar will know what to do with it.

If your program writes the data directly to the *interessen_c* field in the database, then the field contents must adhere to the following format:

`^value1^,^value2^,^value3^`

So with `^` around each value and all items being separated by `,`

Here an example of how to convert the array values to such a string in PHP:

```
$interessen = array();
foreach ($data['Interessen'] as $value) {
    // add value surrounded by ^ to array
    $interessen[] = "^$value^";
}
// transform values in array to string with items being separated by ,
$interessen = implode(',', $interessen);
```

Side-Note:

From within Sugar one can use `encodeMultienumValue($arr)` and `unencodeMultienum($string)` to convert from array to db-string format and back.
Both functions are defined in `include/utils.php`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works with your solution. How did you know, that the ' ^ ' is required? We didn't find anything in the documentation about this.

Comment: @moses I think I learned it from existing enum fields in the past. However, if you google for `sugarcrm multienum`, the second hit is a [dev blog entry](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2013/03/26/dealing-with-multienums-with-sugarcrm/) which specified the db format

Comment: oh, and please don't forget to accept the answer so that people know it has been resolved :)